# Controlling a game run on a Ubuntu VM without a physical display

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, wine

I am currently trying to run a Windows videogame (UnrealEngine4) via Wine on a VM hosted on GCP. I do not need to access the display of the game, I am WebRTCing the gameclient output to a webpage and controlling via it.

I have tried running a VirtualGL display and running wine through it - however, it generates a lot of bugs that I cannot figure out.

Is there any alternatives to virtual displays? Has anyone had any luck with xvfb getting a game client to run using it?

I am using a headless Nvidia T4 and lightDM, any suggestions or approaches would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I am kinda curious which game it is. Most require you to see the screen.

Comment: I'll suggest you to run it on your own server at home, which allows you to access the virtual display with VNC. It's not answering the question, but will make your life much happier.